# SQL: Identifying latest max sequence per row

Tags: sql, greatest-n-per-group, gaps-and-islands

**Current Results:**

[image: Current Results]

**Required Results:**

[image: Required Results]

I am struggling creating Latest_Funded_Seq flag. The logic behind it is to take the latest max Funded_Seq in case Funded_Seq is NULL

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (The answer will perhaps be product specific.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ANSI standard method uses `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select lag(funded_seq ignore nulls) over (order by appseq) as latest_funded_seq,
       t.*
from t;
```

Even some databases that support window functions do not support `ignore nulls`, but this is the ANSI standard solution.

If `funded_seq` is in order (as in the data in the question), then a cumulative maximum solves the problem:

```
select max(funded_seq) over (order by appseq) as latest_funded_seq,
       t.*
from t;
```

Cumulative maximums are also ANSI standard.  In practice, they are supported by all databases that support window functions.

Comment: Thanks, cumulative maximum has done the job - should have thought of this option myself...